# Linq to Sql Connectivity

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-sql

I am trying to fire a simple query of Linq

```
            var user = (from u in Users
                        where u.Username == 'ABC'
                        && u.Password == 'ABC'
                        select u).SingleOrDefault();
```

My problem is that the table Users is inside my SqlServer 2008 R2. How I manage to call this table from Sql and use in my Linq Query. I google a lot on this topic but not find any satisfactory answer. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "How I manage to call this table from Sql"? Your question is very unclear at the moment - I suggest you go through a LINQ to SQL tutorial, and things will become clearer.

Comment: Ok, I will go through one good tutorial and post my learnings here after some time.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly you have to use Linq to sql class and choose your DataBase

you can use this tutorial http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26657/Simple-LINQ-to-SQL-in-C

**edit**

you have to add new element to your project, in `Data` : choose `classes LINQ to SQL` and in `server Explorer` make the chose of your database

I found [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/creating-model-classes-with-linq-to-sql-cs) tutorial for all steps

Comment: yes, you understand me right, my problem was mapping of Linq qery to Sql database tables. After some reading I have found that for mapping purpose we use DataContext class. But how this DataContext class come to know that from which Database we want to map. Is there any kind of ConnectionString we have to provide??

Comment: I read the link that you have mentioned after editing of your answer. But in this link they defined using MVC application. I am not much familiar with MVC as I am working on Web Applications using .Net Framework 4.0 not using MVC framework. But through this link I am somewhere little clear that we have to define one DataContext object and give the reference of our DataBase

Comment: you don't have to use MVC or that you have to use web application, all work with the same way, then you have to choose your dataBase in server explorer and drag the tables that you want to use in your Dbml class and use it (it's simple :) ) if this help you have to accept the answer :)

Comment: When I am trying to add the Sql Server Database in the Solution Explorer, the following error comes: "Failed to generate a user instance of SQL Server due to failure in starting the process for the user instance. The connection will be closed." Any  idea??

Comment: you have to googling a little for this error, there's many answer ,for example you can see http://sqlserverastuces.blogspot.com/2013/03/fix-error-failed-to-generate-user.html or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307864/en-us